# Table with 10 columns out of the page

Tags: tables

I'm trying to do a **table with 10 columns** but it goes **out of the page**. I would like to know if it is possible to resolve that problem.

[image]

**Here's an MWE:**

```
\begin{table*}
\small
\centering
\caption{Some Typical Commands}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|l|} \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Années} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\makecell[cc]{Utilisateurs Internet\\(en millions)}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\makecell[cc]{Utilisateurs Internet mobile\\(en millions)}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\makecell[cc]{Utilisateurs en zones\\rurales (en \%)}}\\ \cline{2-10}
 & \makecell[cc]{Chine\\continentale} & Hongkong & Macao & \makecell[cc]{Chine\\continentale} & Hongkong & Macao & \makecell[cc]{Chine\\continentale} & Hongkong & Macao\\ \hline

2007 & 210 & 4.5 & 0.2 & 50 & 10.8 & 0.8 & N/D & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
2008 & 298 & 4.7 & 0.3 & 118 & 11.6 & 0.9 & 28.4 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
2009 & 384 & 4.8 & 0.3 & 233 & 12.6 & 1 & 27.8 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
2010 & 457 & 5.1 & 0.3 & 303 & 13.8 & 1.1 & 27.3 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
2011 & 513 & 5.1 & 0.3 & 356 & 15.3 & 1.4 & 26.5 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
2012 & 564 & 5.2 & 0.4 & 420 & 16.4 & 1.6 & 27.6 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would be better if you transpose the table, switching rows with columns and viceversa. Otherwise, you can use the `landscape` enviroment, of the `pdflscape` package to put the table in a landscape page.

Comment: The good news is that most of the space is taken up by titles.  Abreviate?  Rotate text 90 defgrees?

Comment: just use headings such as Chine  HK Macao  You could add text under the table clarifying Chine = Chine continentale

Comment: Thank you all! I tested all your suggestions and the better idea was to reduce the titles ("Chine continentale" into "Chine", aso.). Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

One option with simple code is to use `talltblr` of `tabularray` package and at table footnote explain that with "China" is considered Continental China:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \centering
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Some Typical Commands},
  label = {tab:?},
note{a} = {Continental China}
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = { l *{9}{c}}
                  }
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Années
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {Utilisateurs Internet\\(en millions)}
        &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {Utilisateurs Internet mobile\\(en millions)} 
                    &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {Utilisateurs en zones\\rurales (en \%)}
                                &   &           \\ 
        & China\TblrNote{a} & Hongkong  & Macao
        & China\TblrNote{a} & Hongkong  & Macao
        & China\TblrNote{a} & Hongkong  & Macao \\

2007    & 210   &  4.5  & 0.2 
        & 50    & 10.8  & 0.8 
        & N/D   &  0    & 0                     \\
2008    & 298   & 4.7   & 0.3 
        & 118   & 11.6  & 0.9 
        & 28.4  &  0    & 0                     \\ 
2009    & 384   &  4.8  & 0.3 
        & 233   & 12.6  & 1 
        & 27.8  &  0    & 0                     \\ 
2010    & 457   &  5.1  & 0.3 
        & 303   & 13.8  & 1.1 
        & 27.3  & 0     & 0                     \\ 
2011    & 513   & 5.1   & 0.3 
        & 356   & 15.3  & 1.4 
        & 26.5  &  0    & 0                     \\ 
2012    & 564   &  5.2  & 0.4 
        & 420   & 16.4  & 1.6 
        & 27.6  &  0    & 0                     \\ 
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Regarding to you comment, you can abbreviate "Hongkong" to HK too. With this the width of table further shrink and make a space to make all last nine columns equal width by use of `X[c]` column type insead `c`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \centering
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Some Typical Commands},
  label = {tab:?},
note{a} = {Continental China},
note{b} = {Hongkong}
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = { l *{9}{X[c]}}
                  }
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Années
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {Utilisateurs Internet\\(en millions)}
        &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {Utilisateurs Internet mobile\\(en millions)}
                    &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {Utilisateurs en zones\\rurales (en \%)}
                                &   &           \\
        & China\TblrNote{a} & HK\TblrNote{b}  & Macao
        & China\TblrNote{a} & HK\TblrNote{b}  & Macao
        & China\TblrNote{a} & HK\TblrNote{b}  & Macao \\

2007    & 210   &  4.5  & 0.2
        & 50    & 10.8  & 0.8
        & N/D   &  0    & 0                     \\
2008    & 298   & 4.7   & 0.3
        & 118   & 11.6  & 0.9
        & 28.4  &  0    & 0                     \\
2009    & 384   &  4.8  & 0.3
        & 233   & 12.6  & 1
        & 27.8  &  0    & 0                     \\
2010    & 457   &  5.1  & 0.3
        & 303   & 13.8  & 1.1
        & 27.3  & 0     & 0                     \\
2011    & 513   & 5.1   & 0.3
        & 356   & 15.3  & 1.4
        & 26.5  &  0    & 0                     \\
2012    & 564   &  5.2  & 0.4
        & 420   & 16.4  & 1.6
        & 27.6  &  0    & 0                     \\
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your idea is the same as David Carlisle's and 'John Kormylo's. I abbreviated « Chine continentale » into « Chine » and « Hongkong » into « HK ». As your table is better than mine, I'll keep it!

Comment: @Guillaume, you still can abbreviate "HongKong" to HK. Well, extend their ideaa a bit by adding table notes ...

Comment: I've tried but I don't know how to add a new note. How can I do it? I've tried that but it didn't work:

note{a} = {Chine continentale}
note{b} = {Hongkong}
...

Comment: @Guillaume, eee edited answer.

Comment: thank youuuuuuu! :)